# gmail api forbidden error with using the access token

Tags: python, django, gmail

I am trying to use gmail api to get data from it. The following is program worflow. First I submit request to google server so user can give my app designated permissions:

```
def oauth_connect(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated():
        auth_uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&approval_prompt=force'.format(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, HOSTNAME_URI + 'oauth2callback')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_uri)
```

In callback, I persist access token sent by google. I was also expecting refresh token to be in the response but apparently it is not there.

```
def google_oauth_return(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated():
        # Get the auth code from the GET request
        code = request.GET['code']
        agent = Agent.objects.get(user=request.user)

        # Create a list of 2-tuples for the parameters to send in the POST request back to eventbrite to get the auth token
        post_data = [('code', code), ('client_secret', GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET), ('client_id', GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID), 
            ('redirect_uri', HOSTNAME_URI + 'oauth2callback'), ('grant_type', 'authorization_code'),
        ]

        # Send POST request and get json sent back
        result = urllib2.urlopen('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
        pprint.pprint(result)
        # Load the json into a python dict
        data = json.load(result)
        pprint.pprint(data)
        # Get the access token
        access_token = data['access_token']
        expiration_time = data['expires_in']
        if 'refresh_token' in data:
            refresh_token = data['refresh_token']
        else:
            refresh_token = ''
        agent.google_access_token = access_token
        agent.google_access_token_expiration_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc()) + timedelta(seconds=int(expiration_time))
        agent.google_refresh_token = refresh_token
        agent.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
```

But when I use access token to pull in data I http 403 forbidden error.

```
def get_gmail_data(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        agent = Agent.objects.get(user=request.user)
        access_token = agent.google_access_token
        pprint.pprint(access_token)
        expiration_time = agent.google_access_token_expiration_time
        # TODO Check if access token expired. tzinfo=tz.utc is used because utcnow returns a offset-naive datetime
        # Set up HTTPS request and add access token as a header
        get_mail = urllib2.Request('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages')
        get_mail.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token)
        # Open the connection and get the json, turn it into a python dict
        gmail_data = urllib2.urlopen(get_mail)
        gmail = json.load(gmail_data)

        pprint.pprint(gmail)
```

I am new to oauth so if anyone can point to the issue it would be helpful.

Comment: typically the token you get back is a short lived temporary token, (short lived being variable, however typically it is only good for a few minutes) you must trade that temporary token for a long lived token to use in your requests

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it looks like you're specifically asking for a token for composing mail (`scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose`), then trying to use it to read mail (`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages`).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/), the OAtuth 2.0 scope you're using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
```

… only allows:

> Manage drafts and send emails

But you're trying to use it for this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages
```

That is, to view email. You need the right scope:

```
https://mail.google.com/
```

… which allows:

> View and manage your mail

So the error message is completely appropriate. You've asked for and gotten permission to do one thing, tried to do something different, and gotten a permissions error.